# How to filter a list using an async predicate

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous

Suppose you have a list of strings (or of any other type, just using string as an example), e.g.

```
IEnumerable<string> fullList = ...;
```

and an async predicate, e.g.

```
static Task<bool> IncludeString(string s) { ... }
```

What is the simplest way of filtering the list by that predicate, with the following constraints:

1. Predicates should not be run sequentially (assume the list is long and the async predicate is slow)
2. Resulting filtered list should preserve ordering

I did find a solution, but it involves creating a temporary list that has the result of the predicate for each entry, and then using that to do the filtering. It just doesn't feel elegant enough. Here it is:

```
var includedIndices = await Task.WhenAll(fullList.Select(IncludeString));
var filteredList = fullList.Where((_, i) => includedIndices[i]);
```

It feels like something that should be possible with a simple framework call, but I wasn't able to find one.

Comment: But doesn't ParallelLinq rely on using many threads, instead of simply allowing multiple async operations to be awaited at the same time? So saying it wouldn't work, but it may be heavier weight than (though tbh I've never used it so I could be wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not particularly elegant, but you can create anonymous types in a `Task.ContinueWith` call from the predicate in select, awaiting the `WhenAll` call on that array, and using the values included in those task results.

```cs
public async Task<T[]> FilterAsync<T>(IEnumerable<T> sourceEnumerable, Func<T, Task<bool>> predicateAsync)
{
    return (await Task.WhenAll(
        sourceEnumerable.Select(
            v => predicateAsync(v)
            .ContinueWith(task => new { Predicate = task.Result, Value = v })))
        ).Where(a => a.Predicate).Select(a => a.Value).ToArray();
}
```

Example usage (made-up function for demonstration):

```
// Returns { "ab", "abcd" } after 1000ms
string[] evenLengthStrings = await FilterAsync<string>(new string[] { "a", "ab", "abc", "abcd" }, (async s => { await Task.Delay(1000); return s.Length % 2 == 0; }));
```

Note that even without the `ToArray` call, the returned enumerable will *not* re-enumerate the source enumerable when enumerated - it will not be lazy because  `Task.WhenAll` doesn't return a LINQy lazy enumerable.

Comment: A little cleaner than mine as it's more functional. If you rewrite it as a generic helper that takes in an IEnumerable<string> and the predicate, and clean it up a bit so it's not all on one line, I'll mark as Answer. Thanks!

Comment: Cleaned it up, now generic and properly taking a predicate. Still one statement, I can separate out the temporary lazy enumerator onto a separate line if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own implementation of the `Linq` function you need, i.e.

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<TIn>> FilterAsync<TIn>(this IEnumerable<TIn> source, Func<TIn, Task<bool>> action)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));

    var result = new List<TIn>();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (await action(item))
        {
            result.Add(item);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then you can use it like so

```
IEnumerable<string> example = new List<string> { "a", "", null, "   ", "e" };
var validStrings = await example.FilterAsync(IncludeString);
// returns { "a", "e" }
```

given this implementation of `IncludeString`

```
public static Task<bool> IncludeString(string s) {
    return Task.FromResult(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));
}
```

So it basically runs an `async Func<int, Task<bool>>` for each item in the list

Comment: Your implementation runs the predicate sequentially on each item, so it would run very slowly. See the constraints I listed in the question.

Comment: Is it supposed to be a filter? how can you guarantee integrity when concurrent filters are operating in the same collection?

Comment: The input list should be viewed as read-only, and each element is independent of others. So that is not a concern.